# how to disable .desktop entry file from showing up in Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, .desktop

In the Unity launcher, when I type "emacs" I get both "Emacs (GUI)" and "Emacs (Terminal)". I just want the GUI version. I see `/usr/share/applications/emacs.desktop` and `/usr/share/applications/emacs-term.desktop`, and [this wiki page on Desktop entries](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries#Hide_desktop_entries) and the [FreeDesktop spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#recognized-keys) indicates that adding `NoDisplay=true` will disable the "terminal" version, but doing so isn't working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be...just wait? While trying to figure this out, I did try logging out and back in again, but eventually this seemed to work.

Note that one problem with directly editing the `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` is that if the package is upgraded, it will overwrite your changes. But [the wiki page above](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries#Hide_desktop_entries) mentions that you can make a copy of the file in your home directory -- `~/.local/share/applications` -- add the `NoDisplay=true` there, and then even if the original `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` is modified, your version will take precedence and the entry won't display.